# xsl href not working in chrome

Tags: html, firefox, xslt, google-chrome, xslt-1.0

I have used the following code in my XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(concat('#',$chapter2))/>

<a href="{$link}">Next chapter</a>
```

It should navigate to chapter 2 position on click of the next  chapter link.
Its not navigating to chapter 2 in chrome and firefox. When I hover to the link I found that in chrome and firefox after '#' some extra characters gets added like #14678776e_chapter2.

How to fix this issue.

$chapter2 is position() value
Code:

```
<xsl:variable name=chapter2 select="position()"/>
```

Code for xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform";
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
        exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"> 

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="link" select="concat('#',$chapter)"/>
        <a href="{$link}" title="{$link}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is no input xml for now. The above code can be run directly

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Try `<a href="{$link}" title="{$chapter2}">Next chapter</a>`. When the mouse-tip says `"14678776e_chapter2"` (I would bet it does) then check how `$chapter2` is created.

Comment: Yes, please provide us with details on how $chapter2 is created and we might be able to help further.

Comment: @Tomalak - The mouse tip says chapter 2 name but the status bar shows 14678776e_chapter2

Comment: @sam Please provide a short (!) XML and XSLT sample that shows this problem. I do not want your entire code, write a sample that specifically shows this issue.

Comment: @Tomalak the sample code is: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="link" select="concat('#',$chapter)"/>
    <a href="{$link}" title="{$link}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$link"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @sam It's best to add your code to the question, instead of posting it as a comment. You should also add the respective XML.

Comment: Two typos in there: Wrong namespace in the `xmlns:xsl` attribute. A semicolon (`;`) after the `xmlns:xsl` attribute.
It should read `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name "chapter2" needs to be surrounded by quotes:

```
<xsl:variable name=chapter2 select="position()"/>
```

Also, make sure the template that defines chapter2 is not the same that defines chapter1, or else the variable binding of chapter1 will shadow the variable binding of chapter2, since both will equal the result of the position function. This code works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pitarget.xml"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                >
<xsl:variable name="gal" select="'howdy'"/>
<?var gal?><!--howdy-->
<?echo gal?>
<?html5 ?>

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" version="" indent="yes" standalone="no" media-type="text/html" omit-xml-declaration="no" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="processing-instruction()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="link" select="concat('#',$chapter)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="processing-instruction('html5')"/>
  <a href="{$link}" title="{$link}"><xsl:value-of select="$link"/></a>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('echo')">
  <xsl:variable name="chapter2" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="link" select="normalize-space(concat('#',$chapter2))"/>
  <a href="{$link}">Next chapter</a>
  <xsl:value-of select="//xsl:variable/@select[../@name=current()]"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(document('pitarget.xml')//*) - 1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('var')">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="{.}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="./following-sibling::node()"/>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```